# VS Code Interactive is not rendering tqdm.notebook properly

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, ipython, ipywidgets, tqdm

I used to use from `tqdm.auto import tqdm` and when I was in VS Code Interactive, I would get nice outputs of `tqdm` like so:

[image: tqdm.notebook image]

I setup a new environment with venv, and now I've lost that - only the text version works:

[image: tqdm.auto import tqdm only works with text]

When I run this sample cell:

```
from tqdm.auto import tqdm
import time
for i in tqdm(range(10)):
    time.sleep(.1)
```

I get nothing outputted:

[image: no outputs :(]

I noticed some errors in the jupyter logs:

```
info 13:23:28.399: Execute Cell 2 Interactive-1.interactive
info 13:23:28.476: Widget Message: WidgetManager: Loading class LayoutModel:@jupyter-widgets/base:2.0.0
info 13:23:28.525: Widget Message: WidgetManager: Loading class ProgressStyleModel:@jupyter-widgets/controls:2.0.0
info 13:23:28.526: Widget Message: WidgetManager: Loading class FloatProgressModel:@jupyter-widgets/controls:2.0.0
info 13:23:28.527: Widget Message: WidgetManager: Loading class LayoutModel:@jupyter-widgets/base:2.0.0
info 13:23:28.527: Widget Message: WidgetManager: Loading class HTMLStyleModel:@jupyter-widgets/controls:2.0.0
info 13:23:28.527: Widget Message: WidgetManager: failed, Loading class HTMLStyleModel:@jupyter-widgets/controls:2.0.0
info 13:23:28.527: Widget Message: WidgetManager: failed, Loading class HTMLStyleModel:@jupyter-widgets/controls:2.0.0
error 13:23:28.532: Widget load failure {} {
  className: 'HTMLStyleModel',
  moduleName: '@jupyter-widgets/controls',
  moduleVersion: '2.0.0',
  cdnsUsed: false,
  isOnline: true,
  timedout: false,
  error: '{}'
}
info 13:23:28.534: Widget Message: WidgetManager: Loading class HTMLModel:@jupyter-widgets/controls:2.0.0
info 13:23:28.534: Widget Message: WidgetManager: Loading class LayoutModel:@jupyter-widgets/base:2.0.0
info 13:23:28.534: Widget Message: WidgetManager: Loading class HTMLStyleModel:@jupyter-widgets/controls:2.0.0
info 13:23:28.534: Widget Message: WidgetManager: failed, Loading class HTMLStyleModel:@jupyter-widgets/controls:2.0.0
info 13:23:28.534: Widget Message: WidgetManager: failed, Loading class HTMLStyleModel:@jupyter-widgets/controls:2.0.0
error 13:23:28.534: Widget load failure {} {
  className: 'HTMLStyleModel',
  moduleName: '@jupyter-widgets/controls',
  moduleVersion: '2.0.0',
  cdnsUsed: false,
  isOnline: true,
  timedout: false,
  error: '{}'
}
info 13:23:28.535: Widget Message: WidgetManager: Loading class HTMLModel:@jupyter-widgets/controls:2.0.0
info 13:23:28.536: Widget Message: WidgetManager: Loading class LayoutModel:@jupyter-widgets/base:2.0.0
info 13:23:28.542: Widget Message: WidgetManager: Loading class HBoxModel:@jupyter-widgets/controls:2.0.0
info 13:23:29.464: Cell 2 executed with state Success
```

Comment: Looks like this is an issue with the newest release - 8.0.0

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think your assumption is correct.
After I downgraded ipywidgets to 7.7.1, tqdm.notebook works fine.

Comment: Confirming this is indeed one solution.

Comment: Downgrading also worked for me with:
conda install -c conda-forge ipywidgets==7.7.1

Comment: Thanks. I also tested this inside a venv using `pip uninstall ipywidgets` and then `pip install ipywidgets==7.7.2`. It worked for me too.

Comment: Had the same issue... came to the same SO post (from myself none-the-less). Still not fixed as of 8.0.4.