# How to display two progress bar with tqdm on notebook on vscode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, tqdm

I would like to display two progress bars on my notebook using tqdm on vscode.

I wrote the following code but I do not understand why it is not working:

```
import asyncio
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm

print('\n------ simple p bar ------\n')

for i in tqdm(range(10), desc='simple example'):
    await asyncio.sleep(0.5)

print('\n------ two p bar ------\n')

primary_p_bar = tqdm(total=10, desc='primary')

for i in range(10):

    secondary_p_bar = tqdm(total=5, leave=False, desc='seconday')
    for j in range(5):
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
        secondary_p_bar.update(1)
    secondary_p_bar.close()

    primary_p_bar.update(1)

primary_p_bar.close()
```

It displays:
[image: issu tqdm img]

### Env

- VsCode version: 1.74.2
- In my Pipfile:

```
[packages]
tqdm = "*"
ipywidgets = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.8"
```

### things I tried

I did test this code on a `.py` file and it works:

```
# type: ignore
import asyncio
from tqdm import tqdm


async def main():

    print('\n------ simple p bar ------\n')

    for i in tqdm(range(10), desc='simple example'):
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)

    print('\n------ two p bar ------\n')

    primary_p_bar = tqdm(total=10, desc='primary')

    for i in range(10):

        secondary_p_bar = tqdm(total=5, leave=False, desc='seconday')
        for j in range(5):
            await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
            secondary_p_bar.update(1)
        secondary_p_bar.close()

        primary_p_bar.update(1)

    primary_p_bar.close()

asyncio.run(main())
```

In the terminal it displays:
[image: working example tqdm]

I also tried by replacing the import `from tqdm.notebook import tqdm` by `from tqdm import tqdm` on the notebook cell. It works for the single progress bar but not for two (the secondary prgoress bar is not displayed):
[image: half working tqdm]

I also tried to downgrade `ipywidgets` in my pipFile: `ipywidgets = "7.7.1"` following [VS Code Interactive is not rendering tqdm.notebook properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73407189/vs-code-interactive-is-not-rendering-tqdm-notebook-properly) it did not change anything.